# How do remove gmap pins by type with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to javascript and google map api 3. i want to filter the Gmap pins by filters(office, warehouse), i have added the checkboxes for filtering, when office checkbox is checked than all pins which have `type: 'office'`should display and on uncheck should hide. same apply to warehouse. i dont know, how to write the `filterBy()` function. Your help is much appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-filter">
      <form action="">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Offices</label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterBy('office');"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Warehouse</label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterBy('warehouse');"/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){  
  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: -27.000000,
    lng: 143.000000,
    zoom: 6
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -27.5762924,
    lng: 153.0896137,
    icon: 'img/green-pin.png',
    location: {
      type: 'office'
    },
    infoWindow: {
      content: "<h3>Office</h3>"
    }
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -21.142665,
    lng: 149.186568,
    icon: 'img/red-pin.png',
    location: {
      type: 'warehouse'
    },
    infoWindow: {
      content: "<h3>Warehouse</h3>"
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ["categories" map example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)

Comment: yes exactly, that what i want to accomplish. can you plz write the code in answer